# Как начать изучать Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Я живу в Ташкенте, говорю по русски, знаю VB6.0 и не знаю English! Из это следует, что Microsoft Spark мне не поможет! Помогите выбрать, где можно скачать Visual Studio, желательно 10 и какие книги подойдут новичку?

Comment: Действительно, главное в этом деле - опыт. Просто начните её использовать и всё получится. А насчёт книг - надо всего лишь немного погуглить:

 - [Самоучитель по MS Visual Studio 2010][1]

 - [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008][2]


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5426192/
  [2]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4385452/

Comment: А зачто -2 то!?:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эх...

Фразу про крэк удалил, иначе модератор удалит вопрос. Visual Studio Express 2010 - бесплатен и вы всегда легко и просто можете скачать его с [сайта Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/express). Когда подрастете, и начнете зарабатывать много денег, купите лицензию.

Читать про Visual Studio особенно нечего: среда как среда, просто пользуйтесь, и освоите. А вообще все есть на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/).